# Using jquery ".after" and ".before"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

The first to thank everyone for helping me.
Sorry for my english is bad :)

I need *jquery* use *.after* and *.before* (or maybe one other code)  to add *div* to the *img*, and to run it only acts on *class* (swiper) and it does not act on the *class* structured like it.

For example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="..1.jpg">
    <img src="..2.jpg">
    <img src="..3.jpg">
</div>
<div class="swiper">
    <img src="..1.jpg">
    <img src="..2.jpg">
    <img src="..3.jpg">
</div>
```

And Result:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="..1.jpg">
    <img src="..2.jpg">
    <img src="..3.jpg">
</div>
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="..1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="..2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="..3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example what it looks like your really after is wrap().

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

This function will wrap matched elements with whatever element you want.  In this case wrapping images with a div of class slide.

Possibly something like

```
$('.swiper img').wrap('<div class="slide">');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the answer I need. Thanks for the great support :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('.swiper img').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('img') // iterate until next 'img' tag
    .addBack() // include the current 'img' tag
    .wrapAll('<div class="slide">'); // wrap with the 'div'   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqntjb01/2/